# How to calculate the longest winning streak with daterange

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server which consists of data like

```
userID  amount  startdate              enddate        game    Result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
68838   51.00   2014-05-29 15:41:41.167 2014-05-29 15:41:41.167 1   W
68838   51.00   2014-05-29 15:42:30.757 2014-05-29 15:42:30.757 1   W
68838   -0.50   2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 1   L
68838   -0.50   2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 1   L
68838   -0.50   2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 1   L
68838   0.42    2014-05-31 17:26:32.570 2014-05-31 17:26:32.570 1   W
68838   0.42    2014-05-31 17:34:45.330 2014-05-31 17:34:45.330 1   W
68838   0.42    2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 1   W
68838   0.42    2014-05-31 17:42:12.790 2014-05-31 17:42:12.790 1   W
434278  0.42    2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 1   W
434278  0.42    2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 1   W
434278  0.42    2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 1   W
434278  -0.50   2014-05-31 17:26:32.570 2014-05-31 17:26:32.570 1   L
434278  -0.50   2014-05-31 17:34:45.330 2014-05-31 17:34:45.330 1   L
434278  -0.50   2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 1   L
434278  -0.50   2014-05-31 17:42:12.790 2014-05-31 17:42:12.790 1   L
434278  0.42    2014-05-31 17:46:40.723 2014-05-31 17:46:40.723 1   W
434278  -0.50   2014-05-31 17:51:26.190 2014-05-31 17:51:26.190 1   L
434278  0.42    2014-05-31 17:55:32.870 2014-05-31 17:55:32.870 1   W
434278  -4.00   2014-05-31 18:06:54.937 2014-05-31 18:06:54.937 1   L
434278  -2.00   2014-05-31 18:19:29.483 2014-05-31 18:19:29.483 1   L
```

I want the result to look like this, showing the longest winning streak for each users

```
UserId StartDate                  Enddate                    Streak  amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
68838  2014-05-31 17:26:32:570    2014-05-31 17:42:12:570     4       1.68
434278  2014-05-31 16:57:31:033   2014-05-31 17:22:03:857     3       1.26
```

Comment: +1 interesting problem, think your end date in result set is incorrect. (68838 user)

Comment: I don't have SQL Server in front of me so I can't test, but my first approach would be to find the last "Loss" for each player (try `MAX` maybe), then calculate how many wins are after that loss time?

Comment: That would give current streak, think op is looking for longest streak. Nikhil can you clarify on that?

Comment: Ah gotcha. Then yeah that wouldn't work.

Comment: Edited my answer with the new amount column

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: Glenn's answer is a great answer, and does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, but it doesn't go all the way to doing what you asked for.  I was going to post an answer I'd been working on, but when I came to add it, saw that Glenn's way of doing the heavy lifting was better than my way of doing it, so I reworked my answer to include his way of doing it.  I would urge you to accept his answer, rather than mine.

The below should do exactly what you asked for.

```
SELECT
    Userid,
    Min_StartDate as StartDate,
    Max_EndDate as EndDate,
    max_group_count as Streak,
    sum_Amount as Amount

FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        -- we want the earliest maximum streak
        max(Min_StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as Earliest_StartDate

    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            -- we want the maximum streak
            max(max_group_count) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as MAX_Streak
        FROM (    
            SELECT DISTINCT
                  userid,
                  -- Calculate this streak
                  COUNT(grouping) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grouping
                             ORDER BY startdate
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as max_group_count
                  -- Calcualte the start date of this streak
                  ,MIN(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grouping
                             ORDER BY startdate
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as Min_StartDate
                  -- Calcualte the end date of this streak
                  ,MAX(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grouping
                             ORDER BY startdate
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as Max_EndDate
                  -- Calcualte the total amount
                  ,SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grouping
                             ORDER BY startdate
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as Sum_Amount         

              FROM ( SELECT *
                        -- Assign a group number to the streak, so we can group by it
                       ,SUM(CASE WHEN result <> prev_result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                       (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY startdate) AS grouping

                   FROM ( SELECT *
                         -- We want to look at the previous record to determin when the 
                         -- winning/loosing streak starts and ends
                        ,COALESCE(LAG(result) OVER
                            (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY startdate), result) AS prev_result
                        FROM game
                    ) a

                   WHERE result = 'W'

                   ) b
             ) c
      ) d 
  WHERE
      Max_Group_Count = Max_Streak

) e
WHERE
  Min_StartDate = Earliest_StartDate
```

The output of this is:

```
| USERID |                  STARTDATE |                    ENDDATE | STREAK | AMOUNT |
|--------|----------------------------|----------------------------|--------|--------|
|  68838 | May, 31 2014 17:26:32+0000 | May, 31 2014 17:42:12+0000 |      4 |   1.68 |
| 434278 | May, 31 2014 16:57:31+0000 | May, 31 2014 17:22:03+0000 |      3 |   1.26 |
```

I've included this as an sql fiddle that you can play with if you fancy: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32777/36/0

Comment: @StormCould: This will work in SQL Server 2012 and above, as LAG and 'ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING' were introduced in Server 2012. Can you please share a query which will runs on Server 2008 as well.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have forgotten to include the amount column?????  please include the amount column otherwise it is working fine

Comment: @nikhilshrma Sorry about that!  I have added the amount column, and updated the sql fiddle for you.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to get you started. You can play with the inner queries and start working your way out.  Basically, it first adds an extra column to each row showing the previous result.  Then, every time the previous result differs from the current result, consider it a group switch. Each grouping gets its own number (0 based, and within the context of a user id). Throw away the 'L' groupings. Now you are interested in the grouping with the biggest count for each user.

```
SELECT *
      ,COUNT(grouping) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grouping
                 ORDER BY startdate
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as max_group_count

  FROM ( SELECT *
           ,SUM(CASE WHEN result <> prev_result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY startdate) AS grouping

       FROM ( SELECT *
            ,COALESCE(LAG(result) OVER
                (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY startdate), result) AS prev_result
            FROM game
        ) x

       WHERE result = 'W'

       ) y
```

Result:

```
 userid |        startdate        |         enddate         | result | prev_result | grouping | max_group_count
--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+-------------+----------+-----------------
  68838 | 2014-05-29 15:41:41.167 | 2014-05-29 15:41:41.167 | W      | W           |        0 |               2
  68838 | 2014-05-29 15:42:30.757 | 2014-05-29 15:42:30.757 | W      | W           |        0 |               2
  68838 | 2014-05-31 17:26:32.57  | 2014-05-31 17:26:32.57  | W      | L           |        1 |               4
  68838 | 2014-05-31 17:34:45.33  | 2014-05-31 17:34:45.33  | W      | W           |        1 |               4
  68838 | 2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 | 2014-05-31 17:38:44.107 | W      | W           |        1 |               4
  68838 | 2014-05-31 17:42:12.79  | 2014-05-31 17:42:12.79  | W      | W           |        1 |               4
 434278 | 2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 | 2014-05-31 16:57:31.033 | W      | W           |        0 |               3
 434278 | 2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 | 2014-05-31 17:05:31.023 | W      | W           |        0 |               3
 434278 | 2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 | 2014-05-31 17:22:03.857 | W      | W           |        0 |               3
 434278 | 2014-05-31 17:46:40.723 | 2014-05-31 17:46:40.723 | W      | L           |        1 |               1
 434278 | 2014-05-31 17:55:32.87  | 2014-05-31 17:55:32.87  | W      | L           |        2 |               1
(11 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer 2008 the `SUM` has not the possibility to use the `OVER(ORDER BY ...)`, that make the query little more complex, but not impossible

```
;WITH myID AS (
  SELECT userID, amount, startdate, enddate, game, Result
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (Partition By userID ORDER BY startdate)
  FROM   Table1 t1
), SR AS (
  SELECT t1.userID, t1.startdate, t1.enddate, t1.Result, t1.amount
       , SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result <> COALESCE(t2.Result, t1.Result) 
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 END) SC
  FROM   myID t1
         LEFT JOIN myID t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND t1.ID >= t2.ID
  GROUP BY t1.userID, t1.startdate, t1.enddate, t1.Result, t1.amount
), SL AS (
  SELECT userID, Result, SC, Count(1) Streak
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY Count(1) DESC) Pos
  FROM   SR
  WHERE  Result = 'W'
  GROUP BY userID, Result, SC
)
SELECT p.userID
     , MIN(p.startdate) startdate
     , MAX(p.enddate) enddate
     , l.Streak
     , SUM(p.Amount) Amount
FROM   SR p
       INNER JOIN SL l ON p.userID = l.userID AND p.SC = l.SC
WHERE  l.Pos = 1
GROUP BY p.userID, l.Streak
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de65c/1)</kbd>

The `myID` `CTE` generate an integer ID for the data to simplify the `JOIN` condition of the next `CTE`, if the data showed in the question is not the entire table and there is already a column with the same effect this `CTE` should be removed.
The `SR` (StreakRank) `CTE` add to the data the Streak Counter `SC`, using a triangular `JOIN` to generate a rank for every streak, it's not a dense rank, it's just something to use to group by.
The `SL` (StreakLength) `CTE` get the streak length for every winning streak and create a position ranking by length.
The main query put all together: get the longest streak per `usedID` from `SL` and `JOIN` it to `SR` to get the details.